# Does anybody know what algorithm Google Charts uses for their Histogram Buckets?

Tags: algorithm, charts, google-visualization, histogram, bucket

I'd like to make a table to accompany a google charts histogram. I need to know how they figure out the buckets. They say they use a "very well-known algorithm".